# DiffInMinutes wrong suddenly

Tags: php, php-carbon

I use carbon for managing time information in PHP and it was working greatly. I found out now that when users request 14:00 to 16:00 of stuff it adds couple (or more) more hours on top.

I debugged and it shows things completely wrong.

```
                $current = Carbon::parse($formattedDate . ' ' . $request->from);
                $until = Carbon::parse($formattedDate . ' ' . $request->until, '0');

                $records = array();
                while ($current->diffInMinutes($until, false) >= 0) {

                    $records[] = [
                        'day' => $formattedDate,
                        'hour' => $current->format('H:i:s')
                    ];
                    // This is the part that I use to debug
                    print $current . ' is ';
                    print $current->diffInMinutes($until);
                    print ' away from ' . $until . '<br /><br />';

                    $current->addMinutes($request->step);
                }
                die();
            }
```

So `$request->from` is `10:00` while `$request->until` is `11:00`. The `$request->step` is `30`. These are dumped and I've even tried setting them inside the code.

What I receive from the top code is:

```
2019-02-23 10:00:00 is 240 away from 2019-02-23 11:00:00
2019-02-23 10:30:00 is 210 away from 2019-02-23 11:00:00
2019-02-23 11:00:00 is 180 away from 2019-02-23 11:00:00
2019-02-23 11:30:00 is 150 away from 2019-02-23 11:00:00
2019-02-23 12:00:00 is 120 away from 2019-02-23 11:00:00
2019-02-23 12:30:00 is 90 away from 2019-02-23 11:00:00
2019-02-23 13:00:00 is 60 away from 2019-02-23 11:00:00
2019-02-23 13:30:00 is 30 away from 2019-02-23 11:00:00
2019-02-23 14:00:00 is 0 away from 2019-02-23 11:00:00
```

As you can see all those Differences in Minutes are wrong (the first one should be 60 minutes). This code used to work correctly - any idea what am I not doing right?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I updated to Laravel 5.8 and updated Carbon to ^2.0 and suddenly all my diffInMinutes are not working correctly as well.